# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el nombre del servidor de mi base de datos MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

tengo que conectar mi base de datos MongoDB a Tableau, para realizar un cuadro de mando.

Para ello me he descargado el Conector BI de MongoDB para Tableau. Una vez instalado, este conector me pide el nombre del servidor, usuario y contraseña.

El problema es que no encuentro el nombre del servidor ni en MongoDB Atlas ni en MongoDB Compass. Adjunto una captura de lo que me piden. Si aalguienme puede echar una mano sería genial :)

Muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con 127.0.0.1 o localhost

Comment: nada, el problema es que me tengo que conectar a la base de datos que he montado con MongoDB Atlas y no encuentro ningún sitio en la configuración que muestre el nombre del servidor @AdriánSanzWallace

Comment: cuando lanzas el servidor con mongod te lo debería indicar